# finiteness of a non-negative finitely additive set function $\mu$.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

In the book probability and measure theory by Robert Ash, a set function $\mu$ defined on a field $\mathcal{F}$ is said to be finite iff $\mu(A)$ is finite, i.e. not $\pm\infty$, for each $A \in \mathcal{F}$.

I do not understand the following statement also from the same book.

A non-negative, finitely additive set function $\mu$ on a field $\mathcal{F}$ is finite iff it is bound; i.e. sup{|$\mu(A)$|: $A \in \mathcal{F}$} $< \infty$.

What is non-negativity giving additionally that makes the above statement false otherwise. Please help me understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathcal F$ is  a field on $\Omega$ then $\Omega \in \mathcal F$  by definition of a field. So $\mu (\Omega) <\infty$ and finite additivity implies that $\mu (A) \leq \mu(A)+\mu (A^{c}) = \mu (\Omega)$. (This is where non-negativity is needed).

Comment: Don't we need $\mu(A^c)$ to be non-negative for the inequality to hold ?

Comment: @Tiramisu $\mu$ non-negative set function means the measure of **any set** in the sigma field is non-negative.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I can understand the if direction. However, i am unable to understand the "only if" direction. We have if $\mu$ is not bounded then the non-negative finitely additive set function $\mu$ is not finite. I can simply have $\mu$ unbounded but not be $\pm\infty$ for any $A \in \mathcal{F}$. But this will result in different values of $\mu(\Omega)$ if non-negativity is enforced. Is that it's role here.

Comment: It is exaclty the 'ony if' direction that I proved in my answer.  The 'if'  part is obvious.  @sarat